# Null Spaces and Nullity

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a very basic question. If it is given that the vectors $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ satisfy $AX = 0$ for a $4 \times 5$ matrix $A$ and that $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are linear independent, then does that mean that the nullity of $A$ is $3$? This would imply that the rank is $2$ (due to rank-nullity theorem) right?

By the same token, if a problem says that there is a matrix $B$ which is $4 \times 5$ and has a rank $3$, and asks whether $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ can satisfy $BX = 0$, then the answer would be no right?

I am thinking that the answer is no because, assuming $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ satisfy $BX = 0$, by the aforementioned logic nullity would become $3$. Rank is given as $3$. This would mean that the number of columns is $6$ whereas it is given in the question that it is $5$.

Please let me know if I am making any conceptual errors. I am really new to linear algebra and I just want to know if I am thinking correctly.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Only if no more independent vectors exist aside from $\vec{x_1}, \vec{x_2}, \vec{x_3}$ would we then necessarily have the nullity as $3$ and the rank as $2$.